# How To Copy Canvas As Image To Clipboard Using Javascript Programmatically

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I already use [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/index.html) to take a screenshot of a specific div, now I wonder if I could use js to copy the `canvas` element as an image to clipboard, then user can just click to have an image of what they want on their clipboard, all they need to do is just paste it.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Alexee/pen/kkmVXz)

Answer (score 6):

It work only on https or localhost:

```
    function getScreenShot(Src){
        let src = document.getElementById(Src);
        html2canvas(src).then(function(canvas) {
          document.getElementById("explain-scr").appendChild(canvas);
          canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            navigator.clipboard
              .write([
                new ClipboardItem(
                  Object.defineProperty({}, blob.type, {
                    value: blob,
                    enumerable: true
                  })
                )
              ])
              .then(function() {
                  // do something
              });
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Please note, that sometimes (for example with html2canvas library `canvas.toBlob` is working... not excellent :( I, for example, have problems with huge font-weight styles.